# Any way to do quick one-off compilations from within Visual Studio without the need to create an entirely new Proj/Solution?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, compilation

Is there any Visual Studio tool that let's you run C# code without having to compile an entire project or create a new project/solution just to test that bit of code?

The problem I often run into is that sometimes I'll be curious "How does this code work in this context?" and I don't really feel like creating a new project/solution just to test that bit of code. Is there any tool out there (bonus if it can be integrated into Visual Studio) that let's me quickly compile a tiny piece of code and run just that piece of code?

I remember in the past LINQPad would let me run LINQ queries without the need to create an entirely new project/solution.

Comment: LINQPad still _does_ let you run LINQ queries that way.

Comment: LINQPad isn't limited to LINQ queries.

Comment: @John: Poor choice of words. I realize it *still* does let me run LINQ queries. I meant to say that I used it in the past. I did not know it could run more than just LINQ queries, so I got rid of it (Resharper does my LINQ queries now).

Comment: @JohnS: Do you find that you identify with Sheldon from Big Bang Theory? :)

Comment: @Charles: "what's that mean?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there's LINQPad as you've mentioned. You can use that for more than just queries - you can write fairly arbitrary bits of C# in it.

I have [Snippy](http://csharpindepth.com/Downloads.aspx) which I really wrote for C# in Depth, so that I could present snippets like this:

```
int x = 10;
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

and compile and run those with *nothing* else. It also handles methods, like this:

```
static int Foo()
{
    return 10;
}
...
Console.WriteLine(Foo());
```

It's got no Intellisense etc, but it *may* be good enough for you :)

Comment: What's Chapter 8, 11, and 13 for?

Comment: @myermian: They were different solutions in the source code for the book; the rest was all in one solution.

Answer (score 3):

Not in Visual Studio, but check out "STFU and Code" http://www.stfuandcode.net/

It let's you compile small apps for testing. Although you'll have to make sure you bring along all the supporting code.

Comment: +1 I love their explanation of what we're stuck with right now (because that's exactly how I feel!)

Comment: Not really the best name for the app though, I don't think the company will approve of us using this tool.